# Inject user associated data into REST API method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's suppose we have a *Spring Boot* application which manages multiple users, the user's tasks and the user's friends. A `User` can have multiple `Task`s associated and also can have multiple `Friend`s.

Spring Boot allows to inject the current user via a definition of `@CurrentUser` annotation like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@AuthenticationPrincipal
public @interface CurrentUser {

}
```

Therefore, it is possible to implement the following REST API controller methods:

```
@...
public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasks(@CurrentUser CustomUserDetails currentUser) {
    List<Task> result = taskService.getTasksForUser(currentUser.getId()); // NOTE: taskService is @Autowired
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}

@...
public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getSharedTasks(@CurrentUser CustomUserDetails currentUser) {
    List<Friend> friends = friendService.getFriendsForUser(currentUser.getId());
    List<Task> tasks = taskService.getTasksForUser(currentUser.getId());
    List<Task> result = tasks.stream().filter(x -> x.isSharedWith(friends)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

I would like to get rid of the explicit calls to `Service` or `Repository` implementations to fetch `Task`s and `Friend`s.
I would prefer method signatures like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasks(@CurrentUser CustomUserDetails currentUser,
                                           @CurrentUserTasks List<Task> userTasks) { ... }

public ResponseEntity<List<Task>> getTasks(@CurrentUser CustomUserDetails currentUser,
                                           @CurrentUserTasks List<Task> userTasks,
                                           @CurrentUserFriends List<Friend> userFriends) { ... }
```

Additionally, I would like to provide a custom method to actually define which `Task`s and `Friend`s are provided for a given user, e.g.:

```
public List<Friend> getFriendsForUser(CustomUserDetails user) { ... }
```

Does Spring Boot provide a possibility to inject such data into a REST API method?

Comment: Did you look at Producer in combination with AnnotationLiterals? I'm not working with Spring Boot but I think it might be possible with those.

Comment: i can't find `@CurrentUser` annotation in spring boot.

Comment: `@CurrentUser` ist defined in OP.